# Update multiple contacts failing

Tags: contacts, upgrade, batches

Using the 'Update multiple contacts' action and a profile we get failures on large batches. The profile has 13 fields with 6 of them required by the profile.

If the update is run on one batch of 100 contacts, it fails complaining about multiple fields "... is a required field" despite a value being present. All the failing records are at the end of the batch.

If the same update is run as 2 batches of 50 contacts, it works as expected.

Answer (score 2):

The problem was caused by the `max_input_vars` php setting being too low.  The effect of this is that `$_POST` is truncated and therefore the form was failing the required field validations since the data was not actually reaching the form.

Raising `max_input_vars` from 1000 to 2000 in php.ini resolved the problem.

However, if the profile does not have validation rules the form is processed with the truncated data resulting in data loss (depending on the field type).